# how do you assert an exception from another ruby module is thrown? (using assert_throws)

Tags: ruby, module, symbols, testunit

I'm trying to write code like this:

```
assert_throws(:ExtractionFailed) { unit.extract_from('5 x 2005')}
```

`ExtractionFailed` is a trivial subclass of `Exception`, and under test/unit, I'm trying to assert that it is thrown when I call unit.extract_from(... bad data...)

I've moved `ExtractionFailed` into the SemanticText module, so now test/unit says:

```
<:ExtractionFailed> expected to be thrown but
<:"SemanticText::ExtractionFailed"> was thrown.
```

I tried writing assert_throws(:SemanticText::ExtractionFailed) {...} but I got the rather confusing message: `TypeError: SemanticText is not a class/module`

I can make it work by doing the following (although it seems like a hack):

```
  assert_throws(SemanticText::ExtractionFailed.to_s.to_sym) { unit.extract_from('5 x 2005')}
```

So what's the right way to say this assertion in ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put quotes around the symbol name after the colon e.g.

```
assert_throws(:"SemanticText::ExtractionFailed") { unit.extract_from('5 x 2005')}
```

The quotes are necessary for a symbol that contains colons or other special characters.

If you try `:"SemanticText::ExtractionFailed".class` in irb you will see that it is a `Symbol`, removing the need to use `to_s` and/or `to_sym`.